# JS Array: Filtering out columns in a table

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, antd

I am trying to implement hooks version of this table, but I get some odd errors when I try to write the loop. It has something to do with the syntax and I cannot write a for loop inside my react app. How would I do this using forEach loop? I am posting my code snippets below.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/antd-showhidecolumns

The errors I get are:

1. Unary operator '++' used
2. Expected property shorthand

```
    const onChange = (e) => {
    let {checkedColumns} = colmenu
    if (e.target.checked) {
      checkedColumns = checkedColumns.filter((id) => {
        return id !== e.target.id
      })
    } else if (!e.target.checked) {
      checkedColumns.push(e.target.id)
    }
    let filtered = colmenu.initialColumns;
    for(let i =0;i< checkedColumns.length; i++)
    filtered = filtered.filter(el => {return el.dataIndex !== checkedColumns[i]})
    setColmenu({columns: filtered, checkedColumns: checkedColumns})
    }
```

other functions shown in the demo are working fine, It's just the filtering out the columns part I get errors.

Comment: Could you explain the logic you're implementing here? You can avoid using a regular `for` loop by using `forEach`:

`checkedColumns.forEach((column) => {
      filtered = filtered.filter((el) => 
        el.dataIndex !== column
      )
    })`

Comment: I don't see any errors in your stackblitz example. Is it an editor warning? Or a linting warning?

Comment: @TomTomTom Hey thanks for responding, the stackblitz example was just a demo, I am trying to build a hooks version of it and then I get errors.

Comment: @KrzysztofWoliński I have tried it but I got confused... What would I replace the checkedColumns[i] with, when I am writing a forEach loop.

Comment: Ah gotcha. To me, they look like linting errors. Nothing may be wrong with the actual code, but you may have stricter linting settings. Feel free to see the answer below if it may help. There shouldn't really be any issues using for loops inside of hooks.

Comment: @TomTomTom .. similarly is there a rule I can disable for Expected property shorthand?

Comment: I would try the methods in the answer below, but with: `object-shorthand` instead of `no-plusplus`. Not 100% sure though as I can't test this myself at the moment.

Comment: @WildThing if solution is OK, can you mark the answer as correct?

Comment: Hey @TomTomTom, no the issue was not fixed for some reason my array methods are not working as required. I think its because I am declaring variables from state the wring way, please find my fork here https://stackblitz.com/edit/antd-showhidecolumns-rdyc8h

Comment: You could try something like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/antd-showhidecolumns-f8g5gb?file=index.js. Just went in and was fiddling around a bit, you may have already gotten this figured out though, either way

Answer (score 1):

These appear to be linting errors, your stackblitz example seems to work fine.

ESLint has a rule, [no-plusplus](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-plusplus) that you can disable in a few ways. ex:

You can disable a rule for a whole file if you put this at the top of the file:
`/* eslint-disable no-plusplus */`

You can disable a rule for the line below this comment:
`// eslint-disable-next-line no-plusplus`

Or you can disable a rule inline:
`for (let i = 0; i < xyz; i++) // eslint-disable-line no-plusplus`

You can also disable rules project wide in your [eslint configuration file](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/configuration-files#configuration-file-formats).

It looks like the other linting error is [object shorthand,](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/object-shorthand) feel free to read up here. You can take the same approach as above, or fix it to reflect your current linting settings.